# Mimic audio: Graph in real-time that compares prior (saved) violin sound vs new incoming violin sound from mic

Tags: windows, android, music

I'm looking for a Windows or Android app, that compares pre-saved audio with new incoming sound. For example, if I want to mimic a specific 15-second violin piece that I've never played before, then:

1. I upload the original mp3 file into the software, on my phone or pc.
2. Try to re-create the same sound with my own violin. My phone or PC receives that as the sound input.
3. See the graph/pattern for both pieces of music, and compare the similarities and differences.

It'd be great if this could be done in real-time! Bonus points if it's free, cause I'm on a budget.